# Inserindo dados manualmente em uma tabela (Android)

Tags: android

Meu projeto tem um TextView que já deveria iniciar exibindo um valor ao usuário, esse terá apenas que alterá-lo. Mas, esse valor não está sendo exibido. Acredito que ele não está sendo gravado. Como faço para inserir esse valor inicial na tabela?

Este é o código que estou usando e não dá certo:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase bd) {
    bd.execSQL("create table dados(_id integer primary key autoincrement, data text not null);");
    String sql = "INSERT INTO dados (data) values('DD/MM/AAAA')";
    bd.execSQL(sql);
}
```

Comment: O que é que não está dando certo?

Comment: Eu quero que quando o programa seja iniciado pela primeira vez pelo usuário, apareça uma data já para o usuário para que ele apenas possa editá-la depois. Mas essa data inicial que estou tentando colocar não está gravando no banco.

Comment: E enquanto essa data não for alterada pelo usuário, a que foi inserida inicialmente permanece.

Comment: Tem como verificar se o método `onCreate` esta sendo chamado? Ao mesmo tempo, poderia incluir o código que recupera o registro do BD e a classe do `SQLiteOpenHelper`?